# echo array value return form facebook api php

Tags: php, arrays, facebook

i am trying to display array values return from facebook api. array is stored in `$result` below is my array

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Ravi Shankar
                    [id] => 10206576743272319
                )

        )

    [paging] => Array
        (
            [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/1705944052976370/friends?limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_AdBV9ZBlJwwdjBL8iWeIAZBSxDqJO0gvQWS45qwBBg1X8tCbZAoj9Cz506ZCGuDnddOL07MZD
        )

    [summary] => Array
        (
            [total_count] => 4628
        )

)
```

i tried using foreach but confused

```
 foreach($result as $key=>$value){

    echo $key."-".$value."<br />";
    }
```

i want to display the result like below:

```
    name    id
    xxxx   123456
    yyyy   173453
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `foreach` in the `$result["data"]`:

```
foreach ($result["data"] as $friend) {
  echo "{$friend["id"]} => {$friend["name"]}";
}
```

The each `$friend` variable is an array, of this format:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Ravi Shankar
    [id] => 10206576743272319
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Write your foreach loop as below:-

```
foreach($result['data'] as $key=>$value){
        echo $value['name'].'-'.$value['id']."<br>";           
}
```

Hope it will help you :)